# Java - Printing to a receipt printer

Tags: java, printing, receipt

I need to print a few lines to a receipt printer (Star TSP100). I can write the text to a file and use this line to print:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File("test.txt"));
```

The problem is that the text size when I do this is very tiny. Since the file is plain text, I don't know how to adjust the size.

What's the easiest way to make this text readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending lpr commands directly to the printer results in a reasonable text size. This solution works for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `TXT` file to an `RTF` ([Rich Text Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)) file! `java.io.File` can read a lot of different types!

But... if you want to have full control over what you print, draw everything to a `Graphics2D` object, then print that. There's a nice tutorial on how to do that [here](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-Printing.html).

Comment: I need to write to the file programatically, so I can't just create an .rtf externally and read it in.

Comment: @JamesHarpe You could try to convert the TXT to an RTF. I'm not sure there's a simple solution for your problem.